# Running chameleon clustering on python and meet "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", with detailed faulthandler info. Need help please~

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm new in python and programming. Recently working on chameleon clustering algorithm. After running sample code:

```
python -i main.py
```

it can build kNN graph but when clustering start, it gives error:

```
Building kNN graph (k = 20)...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 788/788 [00:03<00:00, 214.07it/s]
Begin clustering...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I import faulthandler in the main.py. It gives:

```
Building kNN graph (k = 20)...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 788/788 [00:03<00:00, 217.10it/s]
Begin clustering...
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Thread 0x00007f5b5d4f4700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 306 in wait
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 558 in wait
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/_monitor.py", line 60 in run
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00007f5b7cee9740 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/metis.py", line 676 in _METIS_PartGraphKway
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/metis.py", line 800 in part_graph
  File "/home/alex/Downloads/chameleon_cluster-master/graphtools.py", line 63 in pre_part_graph
  File "/home/alex/Downloads/chameleon_cluster-master/chameleon.py", line 82 in cluster
  File "main.py", line 16 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I checked graphtool.py and chameleon.py, and couldn't fix the problem. Code used to run well at another computer with same version of Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, 64-bit.

Original code could be found at https://github.com/Moonpuck/chameleon_cluster.

Some help would be highly appreciated~

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I think this github repo is using edges' weight with 1 / distance. If your dataset values is huge (i was using 2-dimensional dataset with 5000 rows and values was too huge), after few iterations, edges weights' propably will become too small. I've solved this issue with mean normalization on your dataset before start clustering. I can recommend to try the same solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30608381)